# How to special character after 3rd character in Oracle SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle, special-characters, string-concatenation

I want to add special character after 3rd character. Below is the example

```
Current Phone Number:- 123234567
Expected output     :- (123)234-567
```

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 3):

Concatenation, as you said, along with the `substr` function:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 123234567 from dual)
  3  select '(' || substr(col, 1, 3) || ')' ||substr(col, 4, 3) ||'-'|| substr(col, 7) result
  4  from test;

RESULT
------------
(123)234-567

SQL>
```

Or, using regular expressions:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 123234567 from dual)
  3  select regexp_replace(col, '([0-9]{3})([0-9]{3})', '(\1)\2-') result_2
  4  from test;

RESULT_2
------------
(123)234-567

SQL>
```